# Ruby On Rails Syntax error in Welcome#Index

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I was implementing bootstrap into my ruby on rails app and now I've got the following error:

```
Sass::SyntaxError in Welcome#index
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sockets.
Load paths:
  /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/assets/images
  /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/assets/javascripts
  /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/assets/stylesheets
  /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/jquery-rails-3.1.2/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/coffee-rails-4.0.1/lib/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.4.1/assets/stylesheets
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.4.1/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.4.1/assets/fonts
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.4.1/assets/images
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.4.1/assets/stylesheets
  (in /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss:17)
Extracted source (around line #6):
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

  <head>
    <title>Bloccit</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>

Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/workspace

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss:17
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___973947755503535086_42092360'
Request

Parameters:

None
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response

Headers:

None
```

What could be causing it?

Comment: It would be better if you provided the code that was causing the error and post the error results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shows that error is in your

```
app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss:17
```

Please check that properly and let me know.

Comment: ahh! I've found it. Ive misspelt sprockets. Thank you!